# Name of a "gym object"

Tags: equipment, freestyle, gymnastics

I've seen a video, there were girls using a gym object that was like a ladder in a "ring form", like two big rings connected by pegs. What is the name of this object?

Thank you all

Comment: Maybe [adding a picture](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=circular+ladder) could clarify the question a bit. Are the two rings the same size, or is it smaller ring inside a bigger one and the two rings are connected?

Comment: Is perhaps [wheel gymnastics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_gymnastics) what you're after?

Comment: Thank you Martin, it was wheel gymnastics, I've seen the pictures now!

Answer (score 1):

After some clarifications in the comments, it seems that the sport in question is wheel gymnastics. Regarding the name of the equipment, I will quote the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_gymnastics) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wheel_gymnastics&oldid=850416134)).

> Wheel gymnasts do exercises in a large wheel or hoop known as the **Rhönrad, gymnastics wheel, gym wheel,** or **German wheel,** in the beginning also known as **ayro wheel, aero wheel,** and **Rhon rod.** The large wheel consists of two circles, which are connected with six spokes. The diameter of the wheel depends on the length of the gymnast, so that the gymnasts can hold himself on the grips when fully stretched. The wheels are available from a diameter of a 130 to 245cm. The wheels weigh between 40 and 60 kg. They are available in several depths and colors.

If interested, you can easily find online many [pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=wheel+gymnastics&tbm=isch) and [videos](https://www.google.com/search?q=wheel+gymnastics&tbm=vid) showing this sport.